# findRecord() returns error but record is returned properly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a strange error when calling data store's findRecord() function. Below is the function call inside of a route,

```
return this.get('store').findRecord('restaurant', params.restaurant_id);
```

And here are the errors I get,

```
vendor-6605726….js:10 Error while processing route: admin.restaurants.show e.getRecord is not a function TypeError: e.getRecord is not a function

vendor-6605726….js:8 TypeError: e.getRecord is not a function
```

The strangest thing is that the function works as it should since I can see using ember inspector that the query executes properly and returns the correct record. I have an index route that calls findAll() that does not throw any errors. I am formatting my json correctly I believe so I am out of ideas on what this could me.

Here is the json,

```
{"data":[{"type":"restaurants","id":1,"attributes":{"user_id":1,"name":"###########","address":"","phone":"##########","website":"##########","created_at":"2017-03-19 20:42:02","updated_at":"2017-03-19 20:42:02","description":"###########"}}]}
```

Comment: Do you get this only in production? Because in development you would get a nicer error.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. It is highly likely that the JSON payload returned by your API isn't formatted correctly. Remember that [findRecord()](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/finding-records/) expects a single object to be returned, not an array:

```js
{"data": {}}
```

**not**

```js
{"data": []}
```

Double-check DevTools to see what your API returns to the client - make sure it's not an array.